# "It's not working out" meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I was watching "Futurama" in English and I listening:

> "It's not working out, fry. I put
>   your stuff out on the sidewalk!"

What is the meaning of "working out" in this way?

"work out" means work out, in the park or something like that (I think).

It should be "I'm not working out", Is the meaning difference?

(I heard it in [this episode](https://ororo.tv/en/shows/futurama#1-1) 00:38)

Comment: "work out" has six different meanings as I can see on the Macmillan website. Would you add more context? **See:** http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/work-out

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: This is the #2 sense at the dictionary Cardinal points you to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dictionary definition that @Cardinal linked to is

> to be successful, or to end in a particular way

In the context here, "Fry" is the name of a character and the thing that isn't successful is his relationship with Leela.  Leela is telling him that their relationship isn't successful; she is "breaking up" with him, and so she has taken his stuff and left it outside.

The expression "It's not working out" is a reasonably common way to tell someone that you don't want to be their boyfriend/girlfriend anymore.